# WSO2 Identity Server - Confirmation Email Callback in Self Registration REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to register user via REST API of the identity server. Thus I am following this APIdoc:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#mePost

I enabled the confirmation email using the recommended way stated in this guide.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation

Email is sending but the callback URI in the activation link remains a variable `{{ callback }}`. Because of that I believe, the server failed to respond.

The question is how to pass the callback URI in the REST API? What is the name of the field? I have tried putting `callback` property name in the `properties` array but the server return error 500. It is not stated in the doc on what other supported properties available.

FYI I am running WSO IS 5.5 as Key Manager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a long time for this, I found out the property name is `key`. So it should be for example

`{ key: "callback", value: "<calbackuri>" }`

I was thinking the key that has been mentioned in the doc is a placeholder name.